# Understanding notation for differential mass flow rate of a control volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, notation, flow, calculus

Was reviewing some notes on fluid dynamics, and the notes go as follows (conservation of mass for a qubic CV),
$$\frac{dm_{out}}{dt} = \rho u (dydz)_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdz)_{y+dy} + (similarly,forZ) = \rho u dydz +\frac{\partial \rho u dydz}{\partial x} dx + (similarly,forYandZ)$$
I don’t understand what the $x + dx$ subscript means. Is that a Taylor expansion? I’m having a hard time following that step